# PHP server only accepting some images, cross domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

**EDIT**
Thank you for all the help, I have decided to move the front end to the backend server and use the old frontend server for other parts. Again thank you. If anyone can answer this though I will still award the best answer and some upvotes. It truly is mind boggling. Here is a picture of a cat as my thanks.


[image]
<sub>(source: [placekitten.com](http://www.placekitten.com/75/75))</sub>

I am sending image data from my javascript through ajax to php on my other server to parse the data, save it, and return the link to the image. (Yes it must be two servers) I can send some images, yet half of my test images return with the error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *php-file-on-recieving-server*. Origin *sending-server* is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here is the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '*php-file-on-recieving-server*',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        urlordata: false,
        room: 'Math',
        data: e.target.result
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.t'+thumbNumberCounter).attr('src', data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $('.t'+thumbNumberCounter).attr('src', '*error-image*');
    }
});
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *sending-server*');

$room = $_POST['room'];
$filename = $room.uniqid('_');

$data = $_POST['data'];
$uri = substr($data, strpos($data,",")+1);
$encodedUri = str_replace(' ','+',$uri);
file_put_contents('*folder-where-images-are-stored*'.$filename, base64_decode($encodedUri));

echo '*folder-where-images-are-stored*'.$filename;
?>
```

Is there any reason an image would cause it to say that cross-domain is not allowed? I specifically gave it permission and it works with other images. Just not some that I have tried. Could it be the size of images?

**EDIT**

Here is what my network tab said about the failed request.

REQUEST URL:*receiving-server*

REQUEST HEADERS
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:*sending-server*
Referer:*sending-server*
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 4319.96.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.74 Safari/537.36

FORM DATA
urlordata:false
room:Math
data:data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAPACAIAAAAqgF+sAA......(very long)

Comment: Probably something goes wrong on the PHP end, which prevents the header from being sent. The browser's "Net" tag should be able to tell you more.

Comment: I added what the network tab said about the failed request.

Comment: Do you see a response body?

Comment: No. It says no response available. Its as if the server ignored the header. But why would it do that only on certain images?

Answer (score 1):

Dump these three server variables to a file on successful and unsuccessful requests on the image accepting server 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'REMOTE_HOST', 'REMOTE_PORT' and compare them.

Comment: It wont let me. On the unsuccessful attempt it doesn't run the PHP script.

Comment: You might have to identify an instance for an unsuccessful file, comment out the header line, and then try to dump the vars for that use case. Else for the erroneous file, the execution will stop when the header line is executed. :)